# Queuing and working a Laravel job that references a service

Tags: laravel, eloquent, redis, queue, laravel-livewire

Context: I'm building a dashboard app that displays traffic data in the form of charts. Currently, there are about 30 small charts on the homepage, and every chart is a database call. This causes the homepage to take quite a few seconds to load. Caching can't solve this problem due to the nature of data filters available within the app.

I'd like to use Redis queues to queue up these database queries as jobs and speed up load times. I am struggling to figure it out though.

I wanted to start simple, just hard-coding one query into a job and getting it to render the chart after the page was loaded. I'm using Livewire for front-end, so updating the charts once I have the data is not a concern. When I `dd` what I assume should return my data, it gives me a weird job-like object and not the data I'm expecting.

My job class:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Services\HomePageService;

class ReturnSparklineChart implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $dateRange;
    public $granularity;
    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dateRange, $granularity)
    {
        $this->dateRange = $dateRange;
        $this->granularity = $granularity;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->data = HomePageService::getTotalMetricsGraph($this->dateRange, $this->granularity);
        // return $this->data;
        dd($this->data);
    }
}
```

The `dd` returns this:

```
^ Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch {#1342 ▼
  #job: App\Jobs\ReturnSparklineChart {#627 ▼
    +dateRange: array:2 [▼
      0 => "2022-06-06"
      1 => "2022-06-13"
    ]
    +granularity: "date"
    +data: null
    +job: null
    +connection: null
    +queue: null
    +chainConnection: null
    +chainQueue: null
    +chainCatchCallbacks: null
    +delay: null
    +afterCommit: null
    +middleware: []
    +chained: []
  }
  #afterResponse: false
}
```

When that query you see in the handle function is run in the service where it was originally, it returns the data I'm expecting:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  "pageviews" => array:3 [▶]
  "sessions" => array:3 [▶]
]
```

What am I missing here? I'm sure there's more than one thing.

Edit: Turns out I shouldn't even be using a queue/job system here. Livewire has all I need with deferred loading to accomplish this. Thanks to Snapey for pointing this out in the comments of this question. BUT, if you're finding this question with the same problem I was having, I'm 99% sure that the way I was assigning the variable `$this->data` assigns the literal dispatcher, not anything from the `handle()` function like I wanted. Furthermore, I don't believe that it's best practice to directly return data from a job like that.

Comment: why not cache the queries for a sensible period?

Comment: They are being cached. The problem is, entirely new queries will need to be run when the user selects a new date range, client, etc.

Comment: How will making them a job improve the delay?

Comment: Currently, there is no feedback when a user clicks a button or loads a page. I would like to load the interface first, and then load the charts in lazyload style as the database calls complete. Ultimately it will still take the same amount of time for the whole page to load, but UX will be vastly improved.

Comment: You have already said you are using Livewire for the front end, so make each widget its own livewire component. They will each render in their own time.  You can show a loading widget whilst they are preparing their data.  Queued Job is NOT the solution,

Comment: Please check Deferred Loading https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/defer-loading

Comment: Amazing that I didn't know this existed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start with - your approach is not recommended and is counter-effective way of working.

You could:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->data = HomePageService::getTotalMetricsGraph($this->dateRange, $this->granularity);
        Cache::put('data_'.$this->dateRange.'_'.$this->granularity, $this->data);
    }
```

And Livewire poll the cache until it returns something: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/polling

Except you need to figure out how to stop polling after a successful data is received

You could show/hide div on successful polling

Comment: I should mention that my goal is to be able to load the interface instantly, and then lazy-load the charts in as their database calls complete. I wasn't aware of a way to do this outside of a job queue. What is different about this, other than the data being cached and polled instead of being served to the user as soon as it's done? As far as I'm aware, caching doesn't solve this problem because unique queries are consistently being created by the user. Appreciate your answers.